# How to generate a random image in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am creating a dice game however I am not sure how to randomly generate the images so the results are random. What would be the best way to do this, I heard an array would be good but then do I need the case statements if I have an array.

```
/When pause completed message sent to callback
class Roll extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

//Receives message from timer to start dice roll
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //Get roll result
        //Remember nextInt returns 0 to 5 for argument of 6
        //hence + 1
        switch(rng.nextInt(6)+1) {
        case 1:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            break;
        case 2:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            break;
        case 3:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            break;
        case 4:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            break;
        case 5:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            break;
        case 6:
            dice_picture.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
            dice_picture2.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            break;
        default:
        }
        rolling=false;  //user can press again
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: *do I need the case statements if I have an array* - no, you'd just get a random number between 0 and the size of the array and index it

Comment: You could store your drawables in an array, generate a random int and then just obtain your image indexing the array: `array[random]`

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't need the case statement if you declare one (or two) array(s) of drawable images like (assuming R.drawable is the correct type):

```
R.drawable[] dice= {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six};
R.drawable[] dice2= {R.drawable.five, R.drawable.four,...};
```

Then you can just write:

```
int randomNumber = rng.nextInt(6);
dice_picture.setImageResource(dice[randomNumber]);
dice_picture2.setImageResource(dice2[randomNumber]);
```

instead of your switch-code.

As requested a full working example which returns a random text:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomText {

    String[] texts={"Hello", "World", "Cafe-Babe"};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RandomText randText = new RandomText();
        randText.performRandom();
    }

    void performRandom(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        printText(texts[rand.nextInt(texts.length)]);
    }

    static void printText(String text){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, you are right, I didn't realized. My solution is wrong

Comment: can I see an example?

Comment: R.drawable looks like andtroid, and if i'm right then `R.drawable.xxx` are constant variable with type int. And this is just side comment, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Look at edit. It's not nice, but you will see how it works. Instead of printText you use your method setImage

Comment: Look , im going to level with every here, I have 8 hours left and no clue how to make this game, can anybody fix this problem for me, would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Put all your images in one array (like `type[] dice= {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six};`) where type represents you type of image. To perform random, you have to import a Randomgenerator, e.g. `import java.util.Random;` With an instance of it `Random rand = new Random();` You generate random integers from 0 to n-1 with `rand.nextInt(n);` with those you can draw a random image from your arrays with `dice[rand.netxInt(dice.length)]` which you can now set as Picture however you like e.g. `dice_picture.setImageResource(dice[...])`